# Clear the bluetooth name cache in android

Tags: android, caching, bluetooth

I want to clear the blueooth cache.
I'm making application about bluetooth.

I just knowed Android bluetooth device name is cached in the phone. (when phone find the bluetooth device)

I can't find solution anywhere.
I just saw **fetchUuidsWithSdp()**.
someone said it clears the bluetooth cache in android phone.

but I don't know how use this method and I don't think that **fetchUuidsWithSdp()** will clear the cache.

Please Let me know how to clear the bluetooth cache in Android or how to use fetchUuidsWithSdp().

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

1. Follow the instructions of the [Android Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) in order to start the discovery.
2. When declaring your IntentFilter, add (at least) ACTION_FOUND and ACTION_UUID :

   ```
   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
   filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID);
   ```
3. Inside your receiver call fetchUuidsWithSdp(). 
   You will get the UUIDs inside the ACTION_UUID:

   ```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                   String action = intent.getAction();

    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                   // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                   BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                   // get fresh uuids
                   device.fetchUuidsWithSdp();

               } 
               else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID.equals(action)) {
                   // Get the device and teh uuids
                   BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                   Parcelable[] uuidExtra = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);

                   if(uuidExtra !=null){

                       for (Parcelable uuid : uuidExtra) {
                           Log.d("YOUR_TAG", "Device: " +  device.getName() + " ( "+ device.getAddress() +" ) - Service: " + uuid.toString());
                       }

               }
    }
   ```

Comment: I'm not having any luck with this approach. My devices are running 5.0.2 and 4.4.2, and calling fetchUuidsWithSdp does not clear the cache for already-paired devices.